# R Formula Specify

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have variables in dataframe Data1

```
STUDENT COURSE  GRADE   TIME    FEUW    GH  X1  Y6  U9  W3  Q0
```

and wish to create this model

```
model = lm(GRADE ~ COURSE + TIME + GH + X1 + Y6 + W3 + Q0)
```

is there a way to shorten the typing out of variable names for example so i can say

`model = lm(GRADE ~ COURSE + TIME + GH/Y6 + W3/Q0)` ?

Comment: `lm(GRADE ~  . - FEUW - U9, data = Data1)`? Or `lm(GRADE ~ ., data = Data1[, !(names(Data1) %in% c(FEUW, U9))])`

Comment: @JonSpring thanks so much but is it possible to do it so I can write out the variables because there are like hundreds in the real data so being able to say var1/var38 is helpful more

Comment: `lm(mpg ~ ., data = dplyr::select(mtcars, mpg, cyl:drat, gear:carb))`

Comment: I find your question confusing, especially with your comment. What does "GH/Y6 + W3/Q0" mean? is that GH divided by Y6 or all variables from GH to Y6? Your example does not give anything like the notion of "hundreds of variables". Your example should at least have a lot more columns (at least 15 or so) to give a better sense of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dplyr::select` gives you flexibility to include or exclude variables based on name, position (e.g. `1` is the first column), ranges of names/positions, starting/ending/containing phrases within the name, etc.

For instance, for ranges of columns:

```
lm(mpg ~ ., data = dplyr::select(mtcars, mpg, cyl:drat, gear:carb))
```

or equivalently:

```
lm(mpg ~ ., data = dplyr::select(mtcars, -(wt:am)))`
```

---

```
> mtcars
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
...

dplyr::select(mtcars, mpg, cyl:drat, gear:carb)
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08    3    1
...
```

@thelatemail helpfully points out that much of this functionality can be accomplished very similarly in base R with `subset`, e.g.

```
lm(mpg ~ ., data = subset(mtcars, select = c(mpg, cyl:drat, gear:carb)))
```

or

```
lm(mpg ~ ., data = subset(mtcars, select = -(wt:am)))
```

Comment: where do I specify the data? is it data = dplyr::Data1 %>% select(...)

Comment: The data in his example is mtcars.

Comment: Or if you want to avoid the dplyr dependency, base `subset` - `subset(mtcars, select=c(mpg, cyl:drat, gear:carb))`

Comment: I did not realize the same syntax in this case works with subset, good to know. The help for `?subset` warns not to use it for programming (meant for interactive use), are there any particular pitfalls to watch out for in use like this?

Comment: @JonSpring - for a basic use like this, I can't imagine it's too risky. Once it's nested in functions and other environments, then you might hit dramas - e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/why-is-better-than-subset - though that issue might generally hit non-standard evaluation functions.

Comment: Oh, and re: the exclusion of columns - sure - `subset(mtcars, select = -(wt:am))`

Comment: lol of course its that simple, thanks